# Mobile Chrome Web App - change to dark system navigation bar

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app (website with a manifest & service-worker that's been saved to home screen) on a Pixel 2 phone.  The system navigation is white, as it is with all of Chrome:

[image]

I would like to make it dark, like so:

[image]

Whether it's in code, preference file, or even a setting on my phone only.  Is this possible?

Comment: So, do we have to consider it as impossible ?

Comment: I believe Chrome and Android now use black as the default color now, and that you cannot change it. If you have an example URL that we can try, happy to take a look.